# optimization problem about capacitated vehicle routing problem

Tags: graphs, optimization, program-optimization, combinatory-logic

I have an optimization problem.

The problem consists initially of the presence of several trucks, each one having different maximum capacities.

There are also multiple customer orders, each with a different weight.

The problem is to fill the trucks with orders, but initially prioritizing trucks with greater capacity, but on the other hand, if two trucks have the same capacity, the weight between the two must be as homogeneous as possible.

Comment: What's your question?  I don't think I understand the problem statement.  I suspect you'll need to make it more precise.  What is the objective function you are trying to minimize/maximize?  I'm not sure how to interpret the "prioritizing" remark.

Comment: prioritization is related to if I have multiple trucks available, the first to be selected are the ones with the highest capacity.

Comment: Can two customer orders go on the same truck? Also, should this be tagged [knapsack-problems] ?

Comment: Yes, several orders can go in the same truck, as long as it respects its maximum load. But if I have two trucks with the same capacity, the goal is to balance the load as much as possible between them.

Comment: Please don't respond in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question to improve it.  I will ask again:  What is the objective function you are trying to minimize/maximize?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/153759/755